# AFNetworking 2.0 and downloading multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, afnetworking-2

I think the problem I have is in my code somewhere or the logic.

**What I am trying to do**

I have a `UICollectionView` in a `view Controller` 
In the collection view I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` - the reason its custom is due to needing to download and set a different image for each cell. Each of these images is an item that has other attributes such as date / title, etc.

**This is what I have tried**

Created a custom `UITableViewCell` and in that class I have this code:

```
 -(void) setDetailsWithTitle: (NSString *) title Image:(UIImage *) image Items: (NSArray *)items
    {
        int i = 0;

        for (BBItem *item in items){

            BBThumbnailView *thumbNailView = [[BBThumbnailView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5 + (60 * 1), 5, 60, 60)];
            [self.contentView addSubview:thumbNailView];
            thumbNailView.item = item;
            thumbNailView.clipsToBounds = YES;

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Here I am giving the cell an array that has all the items. These items are objects. I downloaded them and parsed them with an XML parser. That works perfectly and when inspecting each object - they all have the right attributes I need.

I'm not using the `UIImage` argument as yet here in this method. The for loop goes through each item in the array and sets the image and the `thumbNailView.item` is the object I set.

Then in `BBThumbnailView`  I have done this:

To set each item and get its URL

```
 (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {


        self.shouldShowPlaceHolder = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIImageView *backGroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumbnail_Background_Big.png"]];


        [self addSubview:backGroundImageView];

        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 2, 60, 60)];

            //  self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [self addSubview:self.imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

self.imageView is the imageView I am setting for the cells. The other imageViews are placeholder images. 

-(void)setItem:(BBItem *)aItem
{

    _item = aItem;
    if (self.item){

        if (self.item.thumbnailUrl && [self.item.thumbnailUrl length] > 0){

            [self loadUrl: [NSURL URLWithString:self.item.thumbnailUrl]];
        }
    }

}
```

This is me overriding the setter for the property BBItem. Each Item starts a download of the URL only.

In the `loadUrl` method:

```
-(void)loadUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url]; 
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            //NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
            //self.imageView.image = responseObject;
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        image = responseObject; 
        [self.imageView setImage:image];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
    }];
    [requestOperation start];

}
```

Now I have put a break point on the `lodUrl` method and it is executed many times (As many BBItems there are) with different URLs for each item.

**The problem**

Each `BBCollectionViewCell`'s image is set to the same image. This is always a different image when I reload the view or close the app and open it again it will be a different image. I thing its the last image that gets downloaded and sets.

**Why I think it's happening**

I think the reason is due to each new request that is made I am cancelling the previous request? Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: After doing some more debugging I think the issue is related to setting the imageView. Each time the request finishes, it sets the same instance of self.imageView to a new image.

Comment: This seems like a reuse problem

Comment: Esenitally, yes. I was reusing the same instance of a cell. I did not set indexPath.row in the cellForRowAtIndex method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want create a queue of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, you can use : `NSOperationQueue *queue`. But I don't think it's the problem.. 
I think you should do that (I change the function):

```
-(void) setDetailsWithTitle: (NSString *) title Image:(UIImage *) image Item: (BBItem *)item
{
    BBThumbnailView *thumbNailView = [[BBThumbnailView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5 + (60 * 1), 5, 60, 60)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:thumbNailView];
    thumbNailView.item = item;
    thumbNailView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

And you should call it for each `cell`

Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas - The function is called on every cell - which is called in the cellForIndexPath - I pass the array along as thats how I store the items from the XML downloader. I'll look into the NSOperationQueu

Comment: but if you pass the array for each cell, then it's normal if every cell has the same image (the last one...). You have to differenciated each cell in your function.

Comment: Isn't the for loop in the function setting each cell to be different though?

Comment: can you try to use my function selecting the item like that: `[items objectForIndex:indexPath.row]`

Comment: I missed the [indexpath.row] in my call to this function. I revised it like you have it and it works. THANK YOU and sorry for questioning you. This solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are not placing the Operations in an operation queue. So when you call start on the operation it executes immediately on a background thread that may only allow one single operation to occur at a time.

2 Questions. Why not use UIImageView+AFNetworking?

Why not submit your image requests as a batch? Or at least run them on an NSOperationQueue

Comment: I revised the code to use UIImageView+AFNetworking - which is one line like this: [self.imageView setImageWithURL: url]; - I get the same result. All images are the same in my cells. For question 2: I haven't down much in the way of operationQueues and thought AFNetworking handles this?